# Sequelize - dynamic search in all columns of all tables

Tags: node.js, search, sequelize.js

I want to create a dynamic search using sequelize in multiple tables and all columns of this tables.

I want all results that include one or more columns of any table with the text inserted in search box.
I try something like that:

```
return await Models.table1.findAll({
        subQuery: false,
        attributes: [...
            ['description', 'name'],
            'isActive'
        ],
        include: [{
            model: Models.table2,
            as: 'data',
            required: true,
            attributes: [...
                ['description', 'name'],
                'isActive'
            ],
            where: {
                isActive: 1,
                description:{
                    $like: '%' + text + '%'
                }
            },
            include: [{
                model: Models.table3,
                as: 'data',
                required: true,
                attributes: [
                    [...],
                    ['description', 'name'],
                    'isActive'
                ],
                where: {
                    isActive: 1,
                    description:{
                        $like: '%' + text + '%'
                    }
                },
                include: [{
                    model: Models.table4,
                    as: 'data',
                    required: true,
                    attributes: [
                         ...
                        'comments',
                        'isActive'
                    ],
                    where: {
                        isActive: 1
                    }
                }]
            }]
        }],
        where: {
            isActive: 1
        }

    })
```

But I get the results just if all columns 'description' match the text. Can I start the query with the table4? Down to up, and return if anyone column match the text?